# Unable to import react component to my app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a couple of components which I have imported to my app.js file.
But after adding two components to my app.js, I am not able to add further components to it.
However, in the import section, my components are getting linked via the name I am giving but I am not able to use them in my code.

I have also tried by copying the working component code to a new component and changing its class name. Also, I have written a simple component and tried to import it but still no luck.

```
//App.js file***************
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import AppNavbar from './components/AppNavbar';
import Players from './components/Players';
// components are linked here********
import test from './components/test';
import playerModal from './components/playerModal';
//***********************************
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Store from './Store';
import { Container } from 'reactstrap';
function App() {
    return (
        <Provider store={Store}>
            <div className="App">
                <AppNavbar />
                <Container>
                    <Players />
                                  //but not able to use it here***
                    <test />
                    <playerModal />
                                  //**********************
                </Container>
            </div>
        </Provider>
        );
    }

export default App;
///*******************************
///test.js file*****************
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class test extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>asdfjokd</div>;
    }
}
export default test;
//*****************************************
```

Pls, help me out to sort this.

Comment: `I am not able to` Why?

Comment: components must start with a capital letter rename to `Test.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when making a component, it needs to be capitalized. You need to change `test` to `Test` and also `playerModal` to `PlayerModal`

In JSX, lower-case tag names are considered to be HTML tags. However, lower-case tag names with a dot (property accessor) aren't.

```
    <component /> compiles to React.createElement('component') (html tag)
    <Component /> compiles to React.createElement(Component)
    <obj.component /> compiles to React.createElement(obj.component)
```

example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Test extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>asdfjokd</div>;
    }
}
export default Test;
```

also make sure you import it capitalized

Answer (score 0):

The Custom component follows a naming convention so the **test** component should be **Test** and respectively applied for others .

Please try by updating the component name , where first letter of custom component should be capital